# GoToMeeting client XP SP3 and 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, gotomeeting

Anyone know if there is any compatibility issue of GoToMeeting desktop application between Windows XP SP3 and Windows 7 x64.

In recent days, I found that if I host a GoToMeeting session from a Windows XP SP3 machine, other participants on Windows 7 x64 can see my screen but cannot control my screen when I give him/her the full access to keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Did you follow the guide here - http://support.citrixonline.com/en_US/Meeting/help_files/G2M050019?Title=Steps+for+Installing+on+Windows it has some good tips on how to do this.

Comment: @Leptonator: Yes, this is general guide to use the software. But I'm asking about the problem. There is no problem to install/use the software.